# Ubuntu file system questions. (EFI Partition, FAT32, VFAT)

Tags: partitioning, uefi, fat32

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS today, I found that the EFI partition type showing on Ubuntu is VFAT, but I always heard the partition type for EFI partition should be FAT32. I  returned to Windows 8.1 and seeing the paritition type for EFI is FAT 32 on it.
So my questions are:
What is VFAT?
Why is ubuntu showing the EFI partition as VFAT, while on Windows 8.1 it is FAT32?
Did Ubuntu formatted the EFI partion?
Does this have any implication on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 7):

FAT has been expanded over time in two orthogonal ways:

- **FAT pointer size** -- FAT filesystem pointers come in 12-, 16-, and 32-bit sizes. The smaller sizes are useful on smaller media (like floppy disks) but impose media size limits. FAT32 is the least limiting in this respect; it can handle up to 2TiB partitions (or 16TiB for disks with 4KiB sectors). The FAT size is fixed when the filesystem is created, and it's not easily changed after the fact. Some tools report the FAT size of existing partitions, but others don't.
- **Long filename support** -- FAT was originally used by DOS (and variants of it by other OSes in the 1980s, and even in the late 1970s), and had a limit of 8-character filenames with an optional 3-character extension (so-called *8.3 filenames*). With Windows 95, though, Microsoft introduced a way to store longer filenames on a FAT filesystem in a backwards-compatible way. This technique is called *VFAT.* Note that VFAT is *not* specified at filesystem-creation time; it's activated (or not) by the OS that accesses the filesystem. In Linux, this is done by specifying the `msdos` (8.3 filenames) or `vfat` (long filenames) filesystem type code to the `mount` command. A filesystem that's been used only by DOS can be accessed later as VFAT and long filenames added; or a disk that's been used with VFAT long filenames can be accessed without long filenames (but filenames will be shortened).

VFAT is compatible with any FAT pointer size, so you can have VFAT-12, VFAT-16, or VFAT-32. These terms are pretty rare, though; perhaps because the bit-depth is independent of the filename length, the bit-depth is often combined with "FAT" to identify that detail, whereas "VFAT" is generally used alone. All of this was pretty well-understood by computer-literate individuals in the mid-to-late 1990s, but the details have been forgotten (or never learned) since then.

Answer (score 1):

VFAT is FAT32. There's nothing wrong with it showing as VFAT in Ubuntu (or any other Linux). If you plug in any USB flash drives, SD cards, etc… they will also show as VFAT, unless you've formatted them to something other than what they came as.

Answer (score 1):

FAT is a filesystem. VFAT, FAT16, and FAT32 are merely versions of FAT that have been extended to include new features. Some software on Ubuntu detects FAT32 partitions as VFAT (likely because the program isn't aware of FAT32), but as long as it's actually formatted as FAT32 you won't have any problems with Windows 8. If you install a program like Gparted on Ubuntu it will show the partition as FAT32 rather than VFAT. It all depends what program you use on Ubuntu, and what filesystems that program supports detecting.